# Sitecore shared db

Tags: sitecore

We are very new to Sitecore and using Sitecore 6.5, and we are using a shared db on the server which we access from local machines and our staging server.

If I rename an item on [staging server]/sitecore, Im not seeing it remaned in [localhost]/sitecore

I would expect the dev server and local machines to pick this up straight away as they share the same db.

Can someone explain this to me?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Simple fix. Go to App_Config/Include folder in each environment and rename the ScalabilitySettings.config.example file to ScalabilitySettings.config. This will enable the EventQueues in Sitecore.

Sitecore caches all database content in memory locally. This is done on a number of levels. If something is changed in the DB by a remote Sitecore instance and your Sitecore instance doesn't know that its changed, then Sitecore will deliver the outdated item from cache. The EventQueue is a table in the DB that lists content changes, which is then checked by each Sitecore instance connected to the DB, enabling it to clear the cache for the relevant items.

By default the EventQueues are off for performance reasons.

Answer (score 1):

can you check if EnableEventQueues setting  is true,

which is a required step to configure Sitecore to record and process remote events,

perform automatic cache synching between multiple instances and run distributed publishing.

I think it's a problem with caching between stagging server and localhost.

Please check next [link](http://sdn.sitecore.net/Reference/Sitecore%206/Scaling%20Guide.aspx)